# Better way to refence pages within website

Tags: php, include

I'm using a complicated folder structure for my website, which makes organizing my content simple. However when I need to link to a page I often have to take this approach:

```
include_once '../../../assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php';
```

Is there a way for me to get rid of all the `../` things?

Comment: `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` if "assets" is your first sub-folder from root, yes. I.e.: `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/path/to/file";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- im bit confuce about duplicated answer that you marked. Cz its feel not relavant to this. Its shows different in `dodument root`  and he asking how to access file using provided details.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

**Method 01**

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php";
include_once($path);
```

**Method 02**

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php';
```

> **Note**
>
> I have found that in some environments `DOCUMENT_ROOT` does not seem to be properly set. I have devised a way that is independent of the server, and whether the hosting provider provides the ability to set an include or auto-prepend path as well.
>
> Each directory contains a `'meta'` file called `'__php__.php'` (or whatever one wants to call it). For any files in that directory, they simply include it as `<?php include('__php__.php'); ?>`. The file itself simply includes the one in the parent directory all the way up to the site root. The file in the site root then can include other files, a simply way of auto-including files even if a service provider does not support it, and also define a variable such as `'SITE_ROOTDIR'`, which can then be used later. If the document files are moved to another directory, they will still include the `__php__.php` file in that directory and still get the `SITE_ROOTDIR` constant from the top `__php__.php` file.
>
> I also do something similar for a simple navigation bar, where each directory has a `__navbar__.php` file, and each page simply includes it at the correct location and it can include parent navigation elements and define its own navigation elements.
>
> One *advantage* of this is that a part of the site can be sectioned in a sub-directory, and still get the root of that part, even if it isn't the actual document root. A *disadvantage* is that it may slow down while doing all the includes on a site with heavy traffic.
>
> Yet another:
>
> ```
> <?php set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ); ?>
> ```

Comment: This answer is just what I needed as my Document root wasn't set properly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
include_once '../../../assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php';
```

To

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/assets/php/DB/DBConnect.php';
```

**Note** `assets` should be your first sub-folder.